# File Upload Causes Page To Hang

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When attempting to upload a file of 35 megs, the website hangs.

I have set a break point on the server side before the File.SaveAs(path) command is even called.

I do a check on the server side to make sure the file is less than 20 megs, but it doesn't even reach this point. The web page just continues to load until I get a connection was reset error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload the file with simple HTTP-POST you need to wait for the whole file to be uploaded. You can't abort the upload earlier in the controller, only with web.config as cosset's answer suggests.

You could use maybe Flash to check the file size on the client already, don't know details about that though

Answer (score 1):

Increase maxAllowedContentLength in web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
        </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Web.config in system.web :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100000"/>
```

100000kb =100 MB

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a good chance to use async as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx)?

There is also an excellent article on async and await [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

Web.Config issues aside, a file that big is going to take some time. I would try not to block the current thread with such an action.